# Unable to write Pandas DataFrame to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert a very large JSON file into smaller CSV files. Here is the code I am using

```py
data = pd.read_json(FILE + '.json', lines=True,
                    chunksize=2000000, orient='records', encoding='utf-8')

for i, chunk in enumerate(data):
    chunk.to_csv('../data_subset/{}'.format(FILE + '_' + str(i) + '.csv'),
                            index=False)
```

However, I get the following error on some of the files (around 10% of them)

```
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

When I search for the error online, it shows cases where users are not using quotes and thus need to delimit the comma. However, this does not apply here.

Also, the error can happen in any chunk of the JSON file - not necessarily the start or end of the file.

Not sure if this is relevant to the error but the JSON files are initially decompressed from `.zst`.

EDIT: I have tried using other delimiters such as `\t`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it as simple as this? It's hard to tell without your JSON.

```
import pandas as pd
FILE = "data"
data = pd.read_json(FILE + '.json', lines=True,
                    chunksize=2000000, orient='records', encoding='utf-8')
for chunk in data: 
    chunk.to_csv(FILE + '.csv', sep='\t', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: I do not think that this code will do what I want as I want multiple small CSV files. As for sharing the JSON, that is not possible since the file is too big to upload and even if I were to upload it, I do not know what exactly is causing this issue.

Comment: A snippet then.